# Failing test on Repl.it for a "Poker face" exercise

Tags: java

I am working on solving an exercise on Repl.it by writing classes that can represent a poker hand, and evaluate whether or not each is a straight, flush, or a straight flush.

After running the tests, I keep getting the following:

**Error message:**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at UnitTests.testName1(UnitTests.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:105)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(JUnitCore.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(JUnitCore.java:49)
    at TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:9)
```

The exercise consists of three classes. Main, Hand and Card. I have written code into the Hand and Card classes as the following:

**Main:**

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  
    Hand h = new Hand( "1 1 2 1 3 1 4 1 5 1" );
    System.out.println( h.toString());
    System.out.println( h.status());
    
  }
}
```

**Hand:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Hand
{
  private ArrayList<Card> handArray = new ArrayList<Card>();
  private ArrayList<Integer> cardArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  private ArrayList<Integer> onlyValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  private ArrayList<Integer> onlySuits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 
    Hand( String str )
    {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(str);
      
      while (in.hasNextInt()) {
        int digitX = in.nextInt();
        int digitY = in.nextInt();
        this.handArray.add(new Card(digitX,digitY));
        this.cardArray.add(digitX);
        this.cardArray.add(digitY);
      }
    }
 
    public String toString()
    {
      String toString = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < handArray.size(); i++) {
        toString += (handArray.get(i).whichCard()) + (handArray.get(i).whichType()) + ", ";
      }
      toString = toString.replaceAll(", $", "");
      return toString;
    }
    
    public boolean isStraigh() {
      boolean isStraigh = true;
      for (int i = 0; i < cardArray.size(); i+=2) {
        this.onlyValues.add(cardArray.get(i));
      }
      Collections.sort(onlyValues);
      int diff = onlyValues.get(0);
      int temp = 1;
      for (int i = 0; i<onlyValues.size(); i++) {
        if (onlyValues.get(onlyValues.size() - 1) <= 9) {
          if ((diff - onlyValues.get(i)) == 1) {
            isStraigh = true;
            diff+=1;
          }
        } else if ((onlyValues.get(i) - temp) == 0) {
          isStraigh = true;
          temp = 9;
          temp += 1;
        } else { isStraigh = false; }
      }
      return isStraigh;
    }
    
    public boolean isFlush() {
      boolean isFlush = true;
      
      for (int i = 1; i < cardArray.size(); i+=2) {
        this.onlySuits.add(cardArray.get(i));
      }
      int temp = onlySuits.get(0);
      for (Integer x : onlySuits) {
        if (x == temp) {
          isFlush = true;
        } else { isFlush = false; }
      } return isFlush;
    }
    
    public boolean isSF() { return isStraigh() && isFlush(); }

    public String status() // return "Straight flush", "Straight", "Flush", or "None"
    {
      String status = "";
      if (isSF()) {
        status = "Straight flush";
      } else if (isStraigh()) {
        status = "Straight";
      } else if (isFlush()) {
        status = "Flush";
      } else {
        status = "None";
      }
      return status;
    }
}
```

**Card:**

```
public class Card {
  
  private int value;
  private int suit;
  
  Card (int x, int y) {
    this.value = x;
    this.suit = y;
  }
  
  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }
  
  public int getSuit() {
    return suit;
  }
  
  public void setValue (int x) {
    this.value = x;
  }
  
  public void setSuit (int y) {
    this.suit = y;
  }
  
  public String whichCard() {

    String isAce = "";
    
    if (value == 1) {
      isAce = "Ace ";
    } else {
      isAce = String.valueOf(value) + " ";
    } return isAce;
  }
  
  public String whichType() {
    
    String cType = "";
    
    if (suit == 0) {
      cType = "of Clubs";
    } else if (suit == 1) {
      cType = "of Diamonds";
    } else if (suit == 2) {
      cType = "of Hearts";
    } else if (suit == 3) {
      cType = "of Spades";
    } else {
      cType = "Unknown card type!";
    } return cType;
  }
  
}
```

I tried to debug but with no luck, can you help me in fixing this, please?

Comment: It would be nice to know exactly what the Assert() was looking for.

Comment: Add the test here

Comment: I got no idea, tbh, it was added by my instructor. I am still working on improving the code, I think it still miss a lot, but thanks for writing.